# System verilog process::state

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Playing with systemverilog, I'm trying to get the status of some processes that are forked.
In order to do that I create a variable where I can get state of a process.
From part 9.7 of 1800-2012 SV-LRM

```
process::state pstat;
```

But I get the following error with irun : 
xmvlog: *E,EXPIDN expecting an identifier [3.2][3.8][3.9(IEEE)].

Answer (score 1):

`state` is a method of the class `process`. You can't create a variable of type `process::state` - that makes no sense. There is an example in section 9.7 of IEEE 1800-2012, which shows how to use the `process` class.

Answer (score 1):

`state` is a type embedded in a class. The BNF does allow you to use it directly, but some tools allow it. You should be able to do:

```
typedef process::state state_e;
state_e pstat;

// or
type(process::state) pstat;
```